# How do I compare two lists of pairs to see which pair combinations exist in both?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do. So with two lists of pairs, such as:

```
pairs1 = [(egg,dog),(apple,banana),(orange,chocolate),(elephant,gargoyle),(cat,lizard)]
pairs2 = [(cat,lizard),(ice,hamster),(elephant,giraffe),(apple,gargoyle),(dog,egg)]
```

I want to be able to retrieve the pair combinations that the two lists have in common. So for these two lists, the pairs retrieved would be (cat,lizard) and (dog,egg). The order of the elements within in the pair don't matter, just the fact that the pair combination is within the same tuple.

Comment: `{frozenset(p) for p in pairs1} & {frozenset(p) for p in pairs2}` will do it.  You could also do `tuple(sorted(p))` in place of `frozenset(p)` (sorted tuples vs hashable sets).  The main idea is to turn the pairs into something that will compare in an order-insensitive way, and then take a set intersection of the two sets of pairs.

Comment: `[i for i in pairs1 if set(i) in map(set,pairs2)]` should work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
pairs1 = [
    ("egg", "dog"),
    ("apple", "banana"),
    ("orange", "chocolate"),
    ("elephant", "gargoyle"),
    ("cat", "lizard"),
]
pairs2 = [
    ("cat", "lizard"),
    ("ice", "hamster"),
    ("elephant", "giraffe"),
    ("apple", "gargoyle"),
    ("dog", "egg"),
]

x = set(map(frozenset, pairs1)).intersection(map(frozenset, pairs2))
print(list(map(tuple, x)))
```

Prints:

```
[('lizard', 'cat'), ('egg', 'dog')]
```